# Set low battery percentage to 15% in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, battery-charging-threshold

I am glad that the low battery notification now shows at 20% than the previous 10%. Will it be possible to get a notification at 15% or change the warning to 15% of battery?

That is a figure which is working for me. So I would prefer to plug in at 15% instead of 20%. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` you can set the thresholds which UPower should consider low, critical or take action.

```
PercentageLow=20
PercentageCritical=8
PercentageAction=5
```

In order to apply the new values you have to restart UPower through `systemctl restart upower` (as root).